# Sparql queries with two variables

Tags: sparql

How can I make a sparql query with 2 variables?
And let me explain:
I have an ontology for historical maps. My entities are:`HistoricalMap` , `Language` , `Color`
and the object properties that connect them are:`hasLanguage` , `hasColor` (the hist.map has language and has color).
If I make the query:

```
SELECT ?HistoricalMap ?Language ?Color
        WHERE { ?HistoricalMap p1:hasLanguage ?Language.
                       ?HistoricalMap p1:hasColor ?Color.
}
```

I get all the maps that have color and language.

How can i ask for the map that `hasColor` "Red" AND `hasLanguage` French?

Answer (score 5):

Because you want "AND", you can just use constants in the pattern.

```
SELECT ?HistoricalMap
        WHERE { ?HistoricalMap p1:hasLanguage "French".
                       ?HistoricalMap p1:hasColor "Red" .
}
```

If you also want to return the variables still, use `FILTER`:

```
SELECT ?HistoricalMap ?Language ?Color
        WHERE { ?HistoricalMap p1:hasLanguage ?Language.
                       ?HistoricalMap p1:hasColor ?Color.
                FILTER(?Language = "French" && ?Color = "Red")
}
```

Comment: :I tried the suggested pattern but it returns "no match found" even though there exists a match."French" and "red" are represented as instances in my ontology (Protege).The words "French" and "Red" are the names of the instances and they are also stored as labels in these instances. Maybe this is some kind of problem?

Comment: This is guessing game without a complete, minimal example.  Please show the data; please say which system you are using to make the query.  Try "Red"^^xsd:string and "French"^^xsd:string because Protege stores strings as datatyped literals usually.

Comment: Thank you! I use Protege 3, Racer reasoner. I tried "^^xsd:string with no results.Finally it worked this way(french & red as urls of my instances):SELECT ?HistoricalMap ?Material ?Color
WHERE {
  ?HistoricalMap p1:hasLanguage <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1284104147.owl#French> .
  ?HistoricalMap p1:hasColor <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1284104147.owl#Red> .
}

Answer (score 3):

you need to understand how the *french language* and the *colour red* are represented in your data.

it should be enough to see how they are returned when doing the query you have mentioned.

querying dbpedia, that would be, for instance:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?entity dbpedia-owl:colour <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red> .
  ?entity dbpedia-owl:language <http://dbpedia.org/resource/French_language> .
}
```

Comment: "French" and "red" are represented as instances in my ontology (Protege).The words "French" and "Red" are the names of the instances and they are also stored as labels in these instances. Maybe this is some kind of problem?

Comment: use the url of the _instance_. (see the example with the urls on dbpedia).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to accept the query but it returns blanc lines as answers...even though there are two true answers...

Comment: blank lines or 0 results? you could check: (a) correct case: urls are case-sensitive and (b) check with `select *`?

Comment: Success! It was the a). Thank you very much!